# PHP file won't work - login form

Tags: php, html

It won't return to the index.html when there is entered the wrong password it will only return to the loggedin.html. Please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?>

<html>

<head>

<title>User Login</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post">

<table width="500" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3"><h2>User Login</h2></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Email</b></td>

<td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>

<td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required"></td>

</tr>

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3">

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my index.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

// establishing the MySQLi connection



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","users");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo "MySQLi Connection was not established:"  . mysqli_connect_error();

}

// checking the user

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user> 1){

$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

echo "<script>window.open('loggedin.html','_self')</script>";

}

else {

echo "<script>window.open('index.html', '_self') </script>";

}

}

?>
```

And this is my login.php

It won't return to the index.html when there is entered the wrong password it will only return to the loggedin.html. Please help

Comment: your action is login.php and you wrote code in index.html. why is it so?

Comment: @MahaDev because I need the form to use the login.php as action otherwise it won't connect to the database

Comment: But how do you expect index.php to run when you execute login.php? What does login.php look like?

Comment: @GolezTrol the seconde snipet is my login.php

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?>` : this is likely to cause you problems as you're calling `session_start()` **after** you've begun output. It also appears that you're storing passwords in the database in plain text.

Comment: @JamieEltringham within the question. Posted two snipets. The first one from the top is the index.php & the second one is the login.php

Comment: @SanderBakker Sorry I cant see second snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
if($check_user >= 1) or if($check_user > 0)
```

instead of

```
if($check_user > 1)
```

Because, with your request, I think you select only one user so, if you make `> 1` you have to select 2 user minimum.

And also, to redirect see [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) method. For example : `header('Location: loggedin.html');` will redirect you to 'loggedin' page.

And you have to use `session_start()` before all other thing. So use `session_start` before you define the `doctype`

Comment: Also use session_start() before <!DOCTYPE html> to set proper session and redirections.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `header("Location: ")` redirect but make sure you don't output any other HTML before, like the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag or any whitespace. I definitely wouldn't use javascript to redirect here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a login form so only one username and password match is acceptable. Definitely the `num_rows` should result to 1.

```
 if ($check_user == 1) {
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
    header('Location: loggedin.html');
 }
 else {
    header('Location: index.html');
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below it will work

```
 $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='".$email."' AND user_pass='".$pass."'";

if($check_user > 0)
```

Comment: String interpolation is not the problem here.